# Multiple instances of the same android compound component

Tags: android, custom-component

I have a custom EditText component (compound component, based on LinearLayout) and I am using multiple instances in the same Activity. 
The custom component works as expected, however, when I rotate the ui, the text that was entered in the second component is suddenly copied to the first component. Otherwise, both custom components function exactly as expected. 
Both components have unique id in the activity layout.

Here is the code for my customer component:

```
public class MyEditText extends LinearLayout{
private EditText mEditText;
TextView mTextCounter;
private int errorIconRes;
private String textHint;
private boolean showLength;
private int maxCount;
private int lines;
private boolean phoneField;

private String errorMessage;

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ZipEditText, 0, 0);

    phoneField = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ZipEditText_phone, false);
    errorIconRes = a.getInt(R.styleable.ZipEditText_icon_err, R.drawable.form_error_icon);
    textHint = a.getString(R.styleable.ZipEditText_hint);
    maxCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.ZipEditText_maxLength, 100);
    lines = a.getInt(R.styleable.ZipEditText_lines, 1);
    showLength = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ZipEditText_showLength, false);

    a.recycle();
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comp_zip_edittext, this, true);
    mEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text_field);
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(getTextWatcher());

    if (textHint!= null)mEditText.setHint(textHint);
    mImageViewError =  (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_error);
    mTextCounter = (TextView) v.findViewById((R.id.text_counter));



    if (lines>1 && !phoneField) {
        mEditText.setLines(lines);
        mEditText.setSingleLine(false);
    }
    if (showLength) {
        mTextCounter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxCount)});
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(getTextWatcherLength());
    } else {
        mTextCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Here is the layout file of my custom component:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_field"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_error"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/form_error_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/text_field"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text_field"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my layout file for the activity:

```
   <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:zip="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error_msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/home_image_red"
        android:background="@color/zip_error_gray"
        android:text="Something went wrong"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/upsell"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Sign in to use all our features."
            />


        <com.myproject.android.components.MyEditText
            android:id="@+id/request_phone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:singleLine="true"
            zip:phone="true"
            zip:hint="@string/hint_phone"/>

        <com.myproject.android.components.MyEditText
            android:id="@+id/request_comments"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            zip:lines="3"
            zip:maxLength="120"
            zip:showLength="true"
            zip:hint="@string/hint_comments"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_request_visit"
            style="@style/contact_label"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/check_home_visit"
            android:checked="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/request_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="Request a Showing"
            android:textColor="@color/pbz_button_primary_foreground_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button_registration"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_link"
            style="@style/FinePrint"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/request_showing_terms"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "Both components have unique id in the activity layout" -- yes, but the widgets inside your components do not.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I am aware of that. However, how would I give them custom ids? is that even possible? And if not, is the implication that I cannot use multiple instances of a compound component in the same activity?

Comment: "is that even possible?" -- you can call `setId()` on them. There's some spot in Android where you can have the system generate a distinct view ID for them, but I don't remember off the top of my head where it is. Or, implement `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` on your custom `View` to manage the state uniqueness yourself.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, I did implement the onSaveIsntacneState / onRestoreInstacneState but that didn't seem to work. I will try setting the id prgrammatically

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do this: Instead of loading the component via id, parse the tree and load it by the position in the tree:

Instead of

```
mEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text_field);
```

Do this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);
mEditText = (EditText) relativeLayout.getChildAt(0);
```

This way, you avoid loading the wrong component when the activity / fragment is re-created after the rotation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the same Ids of your EditText components. Try to remove it id,and create you custom components separately by inflating each view from xml, and adding it to complex layout.